# Как редактировать вкладки (меню) на странице пользователя в Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal8

Я делаю сайт на Drupal 8 и не могу понять одну вещь, как редактировать меню, которое находится на странице пользователя по адресу `sitename.ru/user/%user_id`
Это блок называется Вкладки и имеет twig шаблон `menu-local-tasks.html.twig`
Но я не могу найти где редактируются сами пункты, как добавить/удалить пункты?[image]

Comment: А почему не редактировать сам twig? 
Если речь идет о том, чтоб у разных пользователей были разные  пункты, то можно это делать через php - собирать разный build array в зависимости от ___